# Google Geochart zoom to a specific canadian province

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

after research, I found it's not yet possible to show only a specific province in a GeoChart, but I'm asking myself if its possible to zoom in to a specific province? I can't find any information about it.

Here is the closest I could get (Showing Canada and all provinces within):

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {'region':'CA','resolution':'provinces'};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Note that the country list is not related, I'm only testing zooming. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,it is not possible to do it with options from the API.
What I was able to do, was make some tweeks with CSS, to achieve a similar result.

I created another div around the div that will display the map, with a specific size and hidden overflow. Then I created the map in big proportions and with css margin values I would position it inside the parent div only to display the region I wanted.

For example:

```
#canvas {
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#visualization {
    top:-150px;
}
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/njB6m/

Hope it helps! 
Cheers

Comment: So if I keep in a database the #visualization top/left/size for every province, my problem is solved. That's great! Thank you so much!